# Efficient grouping by key "within" partitions

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark

I'm trying to adapt a process to spark.
Basically, the process analyzes batches of data from a JDBC data source
each record has a batchId, and also a higher level groupId.

- The number of batches is large (unknown in advance).
- The number of groups is ~100.
- The number of records for each batch can fit in RAM.

The actual analyzing code doesn't matter, but it doesn't fit the more specific models of reduceByKey or combineByKey

My idea was:

- use jdbcRdd to read the data, use the "group id" for partitioning
- use group by batchId to prepare the data
- use map to apply the business logic.

The bottle neck appears to be the groupByKey, that from my understanding will force a shuffle (writing data to disk) - even though each batch is contained in a single partition.

The other possible approach is to use batchId for partitioning, but this will create a very large number of partitions - and therefor a large number of queries

Is there a way perform a group by key within a partition?
Any other possible approach?

Comment: You can do almost anything on a per-partition basis using the `mapPartitions()` method on `RDD` -- you just provide a function that takes an iterator on the partition data and returns one on the result data, which can be of a different type. You can do your grouping via a map, which you send back out when you have all the input processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need to use mapPartitions. You access an Iterator over all records in the partition. You are just writing Scala code from there and can do what you like including build up a Map of batch ID to records. That has to fit in memory, mind, but you can always reduce partition size if that matters.