# Index wise most frequently occuring element

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a an array of the form

```
val array: Array[(Int, (String, Int))] = Array(
  (idx1,(word1,count1)),
  (idx2,(word2,count2)),
  (idx1,(word1,count1)),
  (idx3,(word3,count1)),
  (idx4,(word4,count4)))
```

I want to get the top 10 and bottom 10 elements from this array for each index (idx1,idx2,....). Basically I want the top 10 most occuring and bottom 10 least occuring elements for each index value.

Please suggest how to acheive in spark in most efficient way.
I have tried it using the for loops for each index but this makes the program too slow and runs sequentially.

An example would be this :

```
(0,("apple",1))
(0,("peas",2))
(0,("banana",4))

(1,("peas",2))
(1,("banana",1))
(1,("apple",3))

(2,("NY",3))
(2,("London",5))
(2,("Zurich",6))

(3,("45",1))
(3,("34",4))
(3,("45",6))


Suppose I do top 2 on this set output would be 

    (0,("banana",4))
    (0,("peas",2))

    (1,("apple",3))
    (1,("peas",2))

    (2,("Zurich",6))
    (2,("London",5))

    (3,("45",6))
    (3,("34",4))
```

I also need bottom 2 in the same way

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. You have two entries (idx1, (word1, count1)). When counting the elements for idx1, are these to be merged into a (word1, count1*2)? A concrete example of input and output would help

Comment: @Paul...edited my question with an example for input and output.

Comment: And I fixed my answer accordingly

Comment: Are we guaranteed that, for any specific index, the words will be unique? (note your first example doesn't do this  - there are two `(idx1, (word1, count1))` entries)

Comment: yes in an index words will be unique as this is the output from reduceByKey operation. Please ignore the duplicity in example given.

Comment: How many different values of index will there be?

Comment: Index is basically column number, so its equal to number of cols in my dataset which is 512 right now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about spark, but I think you can go with something like:

```
def f(array: Array[(Int, (String, Int))], n:Int) = 
  array.groupBy(_._1)
    .map(pair => (
           pair._1, 
           pair._2.sortBy(_._2).toList
         ) 
     )
    .map(pair => (
           pair._1, 
           (
              pair._2.take(Math.min(n, pair._2.size)),          
              pair._2.drop(Math.max(0, pair._2.size - n))
           )
         )
     )
```

The groupBy returns a map of index into a sorted list of entries by frequenct. After this, you map these entries to a pair of lists, one containing the top n elements and the other containing the bottom n elements. Note that you can replace all named parameters with _, I did it for clarity.

This version assumes that you always are interested in computing both the top and bot n elements, and thus does both in a single pass. If you usually only need one of the two, it's more efficient to add the .take or .drop immediately after the toList.

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP wants (although it's not entirely clear). I think what's  needed is the top and bottom 10 words for each index,not the 10 indexes with the most words...

Comment: You should fix to `sortBy(entry => entry._2._2)`

Comment: Your map should probably return two things - the top 10 and the bottom 10. Then you can do it in one pass?

Comment: I thought he wanted separated functions for top and bot. Added the option to compute both at the same time in the answer

Comment: Using groupBy really hangs my program...I am working with a dataset that has 2259748 rows and 512 columns. Several spark documents discourage the usage of groupBy operation.

Comment: I'm not expert with spark, but it seems that there is the possibility to achieve efficient groupby's using partitions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088981/efficient-grouping-by-key-within-partitions . If that doesn't fit your scenario, please ignore this .

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia...The "list" that you are taking inside last map throws the error that it does not have a "take" function. As per my understanding it receives a tuple (word,count) and is unable to apply take function which is for arrays. Please suggest if my understanding is correct. Thanks

Comment: You were right, it's an array and as such didn't implement take. See fixed version.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia...Thanks for the solution.Its working for me ....Can we make use of the above to find out the percentiles for all the columns ?

Comment: @KundanKumar what do you mean? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is equivalent to producing the entire column list by using groupByKey on (K,V) pairs and then doing sort operation on it. Although the operation is right but in a typical spark environment the groupByKey operation will involve a lot of shuffle output and this may lead to inefficient operation.